# ASP.NET WebForms Передача .docx файла клиету

Tags: asp.net-webforms

Передаю .docx файл клиенту. На входе - он целый
приходит к клиенту - уже Word ругается на поврежденный файл и отказывается его открывать

```
string fileName = "Акт No 2.docx";
string editFile =  "D:\\123.docx";

FileStream MyFileStream = new FileStream(editFile, FileMode.Open);
int filesizeINT = 0;
long fileSize = MyFileStream.Length;
filesizeINT = Convert.ToInt32(fileSize);
byte[] Buffer = new byte[fileSize];
MyFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, filesizeINT);
MyFileStream.Close();
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
```

Самое интересное что какие-то файлы передает без проблем, а какие-то ругаются
например изображения и pdf передается без проблема .pptx нет

Comment: Ага, кажется нашел проблему
попробовал передать .txt, открыл по итогу, и увидел что он в конец .txt засунул в него html страничку

теперь нужна помощь, как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте `Response.End()`, чтобы страница не добавляла свой html в ответ.

```
using (FileStream MyFileStream = new FileStream(editFile, FileMode.Open))
{
  ...
  Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
  Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

разобрался с проблемой:

Необходимо было создать пустую форму с строкой

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="myProjectASP.net.WebForm1" %>
```

и в метод OnLoad формы сделать отправку файла, которую я описал выше